# While with empty body

Tags: java, loops, kotlin

I have a line of code calling a method that return a boolean.
I want to call this method until it return falss. To do so I have a while loop but I do not need a body as all is done isnide the method called as condition.

```
 while (grid.sandGoesDow(500, 0)){

    }
```

Is there a prettier way to do that ?
I was thinking to something like repeateUntil(method,condtion)

Thx

Comment: I’d place a comment inside the curly braces to explain why there isn’t any code needed there. And otherwise let it be like that, it’s fine. (The C idiom would be to put a semicolon `;` instead of the braces `{}` and on its own line so the user sees it; but I think that that goes against the Java coding conventions, so I would not.)

Comment: Let me guess, advent of code 2022, day 14? :D

Comment: Why call the method more than once with the same arguments? It would make sense to call a separate, new method before the while loop starts with the two arguments and then call an altered _sandGoesDown()_ method with no arguments. Maybe you can post more code of your _Grid_ class, especially the _sandGoesDown_ code and instance or class properties that method uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `repeatWhileTrue` method:

#### Java

```
void whileTrue(Supplier<Boolean> action) {
    while(action.supply());
}
```

Usage

```
whileTrue(()->grid.sandGoesDow(500, 0));
```

Beauty is in the eye of the beholder, so that might not be prettier.

Edit:

#### Kotlin

```
fun whileTrue(action: () -> Boolean) {
    while(action.invoke());
}
```

Usage:

```
whileTrue { grid.sandGoesDow(500, 0) }
```

See a running example:
https://pl.kotl.in/4_b_huSfX

Comment: I will go with your whileTrue method even if I would I love to have en native kotlin method for that.

Comment: It could be slightly prettier if you [write it in Kotlin](https://pl.kotl.in/4_b_huSfX)

Comment: It moved the problem away, inside a method with a nice name, which is better than doing nothing about it. IMHO it doesn’t solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Not really. You could use a semicolon, but that's obscure. You should avoid it.

```
while (grid.sandGoesDow(500, 0))
  ;
```

The most maintainable option is to put a code comment into your loop's body:

```
while (grid.sandGoesDow(500, 0)) {
  /* busy wait for condition */
}
```

```
while (grid.sandGoesDow(500, 0)) {
  // do nothing
}
```

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74854774/stacked-and-conditions-giving-wrong-result why the semicolon should not be used.

Comment: The linked question gives a good argument against using semicolons _at the end of long lines_ (especially `if` or `while` conditions); I don't see it as an argument against using a semicolon at the _start_ of a line (where it will be obvious without scrolling sideways). The latter is a common idiom in other semicolon-based languages; are there any other reasons not to use it in Kotlin? (BTW, I think that link would be better off edited into your answer.)

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin you can describe a void action with `Unit` object.

```
while (grid.sandGoesDow(500, 0)) { Unit }
```

Comment: Not personally fan of Unit, otherwise it is a good solution. Thx